# how to combine two MySQL select queries

Tags: mysql

I need to take data from two MySQL tables for that I'm using two different select queries. 
Firs I'm taking ID's (around 2000 id's) from one table and then looping over ID's two get corresponding data from another table.

I want to remove the loop and get the data in a single queries.  At present I'm using the below shown queries.

```
select STATION.STATION_ID from STATION,STATION_DATA where STATION.STATION_ID=STATION_DATA.STATION_ID \
         and LATITUDE!=0 and LONGITUDE!=0 and STATION_DATA.DATA_DATE>='2016-01-23:00:00:00' and STATION_DATA.DATA_DATE<='201601-24 00:00:00' \
         order by state

SELECT * from \
         (select if( count(DATE)=24, MIN(temperature),-999) from STATION_DATA  where STATION_ID=6216 and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00') as mnt  \
         join \
         (select if( count(DATE)=24, MAX(temperature),-999) from STATION_DATA  where STATION_ID=6216 and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00') as mxt \
         join \
         (select if(count(DATA_DATE=24),MIN(HUMIDITY),-999) from STATION_DATA  where STATION_ID=6216 and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00') as mnrh \
         join \
         (select if(count(DATA_DATE=24),MAX(HUMIDITY),-999) from STATION_DATA  where STATION_ID=6216 and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00')as mxrh
```

Can any one give some suggestions.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can u provide a fiddle link?

Comment: link means ?? I'm fetching data from a internal database.

Comment: [sqlfiddle.net](http://sqlfiddle.net) is an online sql compiler..u can create a sample database online and execute your queries ... it really helps in answering these type of questions..

Comment: I'm a beginner in MySQL as this is tedious task for me

Comment: try this... select STATION.STATION_ID,(select if( count(DATE)=24, MIN(temperature),-999),if( count(DATE)=24, MAX(temperature),-999), if(count(DATA_DATE=24),MIN(HUMIDITY),-999),if(count(DATA_DATE=24),MAX(HUMIDITY),-999) from STATION_DATA  where STATION.STATION_ID=STATION_DATA.STATION_ID and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00') from STATION,STATION_DATA where STATION.STATION_ID=STATION_DATA.STATION_ID \
         and LATITUDE!=0 and LONGITUDE!=0 and STATION_DATA.DATA_DATE>='2016-01-23:00:00:00' and STATION_DATA.DATA_DATE<='201601-24 00:00:00' order by state

Comment: Have a read about joins